# PHP script not responding when estabslishing mysqli Connection

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I just need a simple mysqli-Connection invoked from a php-Script. The following script doesn't respond. Would be way easier if some kind of error-message appears, or even some echo-statements for debugging purposes. But no. Only white screen.

```
<?php
private $db_config_file = realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . "config/db.ini";
    private $db = NULL;
    if (!file_exists($this->db_config_file)) {
    $msg = "The config-file <code>" 
        . $this->db_config_file 
        . "</code> doesnt't exist.";
    show_error_page($msg);
}

$config = parse_ini_file($this->db_config_file);
$host = $config[$host];
$user = $config[$user];
$password = $config[$password];
$dbname = $config[$dbname];

$conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} else echo "Connection established!";

$conn->close();
?>
```

The db.ini:

```
host = localhost
dbname = bl
user = mm
password = noadmin
```

Comment: this is inside a class, right?

Comment: you've got [error-reoporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) set to ALL?

Comment: @Jeff No, not in a class.

Comment: what is `$this` referring to then?

Comment: @Jeff Whoops, you're right! Removed every $this. Unfortunately it doesn't solve it. Even with `error_reporting(E_ALL); ` there is no response at all.

Comment: `show_error_page()`  is not defined neither.

Comment: I'd recommend to debug from the top. check how far you get by commenting out critical lines. and check the server log.

Comment: If it isn't in a class it is failing in the PHP parser: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'private' (T_PRIVATE), expecting end of file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to change

```
$host = $config[$host];
$user = $config[$user];
$password = $config[$password];
$dbname = $config[$dbname];
```

to

```
$host = $config['host'];
$user = $config['user'];
$password = $config['password'];
$dbname = $config['dbname'];
```

you are using $host = $config[$host], it need to be $config['host']